# Separating validation from persistence in models?

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures, persistence

Models in an MVC application gets kind of hard to test when validation of data and persistence of data is baked together in the model. I would like to test those separately to prevent doing integration testing instead of actual unit testing.

What patterns are available to keep validation and persistence separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the persistance and validation mechanisms used by the [Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/). Model persistance and validation are fully separated concerns, and there is good support for plugging in your own custom validation code.